# How to upload an audio file on godaddy server from iphone app?

Tags: ios5, file-upload

I have made an iphone app to upload an audio file.

I have also made webervices in asp.net to support other functionality for this app and published  it on godaddy server.

I want to upload/save an audio file on that server from my iphone app.

I have searched many codes but they are not relevant and usefull.

So how can i do this ?

How to get serverpath where we can upload the file?

Please provide some sample code for iphone to do this.

Comment: It doesn't become a better question by deleting and reposting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749777/how-to-upload-audio-file-on-godaddy-server

Comment: @JacquesCousteau-  i have not reposted the question. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using SOAP or Restful services..?

Comment: @Krrish- thaks for reply. I am not using SOAP And do not have any idea about Restful service. : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I POST a file (can be any file , image, video, audio anything) to a web-service

```
NSString *fileName = @"myAudio";
    NSData *audioFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"myAudio.ext"]; //some audio
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.something.com/someservice";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *strPostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [audioFile length]];  
    NSMutableURLRequest *uRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];  
    [uRequest setURL:url];  
    [uRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
    if (audioFile)
    {
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [uRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
         */

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [uRequest setValue:strPostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.ext\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

//userfile -> variable name given in the server code...

```
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioFile]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [uRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    }

    NSURLConnection *uConn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:uRequest delegate:self];  
    if (uConn)   
    {  
        NSLog(@"Failed to connect to url"); 
    } 
    uRequest = nil;
```

I hope this will help you in solving your issue...

Comment: thanks a lot to reply. What is the "someservice" in url? And what is the servercode?

Comment: Rohan, thats some dummy text, you can replace the url, filename etc with the original texts which you are planning to use

Comment: Ok. but should i required any servercode to do this thing?

Comment: Yes, You need sever code for this but I dont have good knowledge on sever side programming and anything I say about it could miss lead you. I dont want that to happen. Please accept my answer ;)

Comment: What should be the content type if I'm posting NSData that is made from NSString?