# How send NSData using POST from a iOS application?

Tags: ios, post, nsdata

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

How send imageData using POST?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code should help

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSURL *yourURL = ...
NSMutableURLRequest *yourRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
//Set request to post
[yourRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Set content type 
[yourRequest setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Set authorization header if required
...

// set data
[yourRequest setHTTPBody:imageData];


// create connection and set delegate if needed
NSURLConnection *yourConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:yourRequest 
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                          startImmediately:YES];
```

Please note that, it is assumed that you are using ARC.

Comment: ok but one must still use the delegate methods to receive the response or error, right?

Comment: What should be the content type if I'm posting NSData that is made from NSString?

Comment: Can some one suggest me what should be the equivalent PHP code to receive the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this answer, if you are okay with using NSURLConnection
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750428/591951

This post explains how to POST an Audio file, but you can upload any file using the same method

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASIHTTPRequest library: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Then it's pretty easy:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Upload an NSData instance
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Info on how to use: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: From  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use : "Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)" So I do not advise to use the library.