# IOS - Format Url send to Server

Tags: ios, post

I have a format url like this:

> NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",http:abc.com/check?para1= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...,1000&Param2=
> 1,2,3...,1000&Param3=12:12:12.000&Param4=1.12310&Param5=http:yahoo.com/adsf.html]

Im using

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [url1 length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response - %@",responseString);
```

but I can't send to server.

Comment: If **you** can't communicate with the server directly, try using a computer and a modem, those might be better at the subject.

Comment: Sorry, can you say more detail?

Comment: Can you say what error you're getting...

Comment: I can't send to server althought Im using method Post, "url1" limited at 2088 character, I wanna send "url1" to server

Comment: Use cURL(command line) or [cocoa-rest-client](http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-rest-client) to test if they string is accepted by the server

Comment: Can cURL use on iPad, Iphone? I send data from Ipad and Iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code, please try this :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *url1       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"para1= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...,1000&Param2= 1,2,3...,1000&Param3=12:12:12.000&Param4=1.12310&Param5=http:yahoo.com/adsf.html"];
NSData *postData     = [url1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];    
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [postData length]];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:abc.com/check"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];    
NSData *returnData       = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response - %@",responseString);
```

May it can help you.

Comment: If you give me your email, I'll give my link url1 for you, because my link is not public, please help me

Comment: now, url1 has fixed the parameter,you can't separate parameter in url1, do you understand me

Comment: No, if you wanna use NSMutableURLRequest to send a POST that you have to separate parameter to set it up with post data and post length. It works for me, I have no idea what it happened ?

Comment: Im using server .net c# 4.5. When I send to the server. 4.5 net how to get the value in httpbody?

Comment: Uses Request.Form["fieldName"], example in your code can be Request.Form["Param5"] will get "http:yahoo.com/adsf.html" string value.

Comment: are you sure? Im using server .net

Answer (score 0):

#### I suspect you're doing it wrong and try put the POST body into the URL.

I deduce that from the way you try to set content-length based on url length.

The post body needs to be the content with `request.HTTPBody = dataToPost`

## the url can't be that long then.

---

I'd advise to read up on the difference between GET and POST

refer to this question to see how to POST data

[How send NSData using POST from a iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753099/how-send-nsdata-using-post-from-a-ios-application)

Comment: I understand difference between GET and POST and I think, I must to using HTTPBody to send data, but url1 with multi parameter was fixed so. Have you any solution? Because if not assigned parameter, url1 is format wrong

Comment: then your code is weird.. you set the POST content-length to the length of the url.