# How to send Image into post method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Here i am Getting image path ,i am converted the path as nsdata ,but in server side receiving empty ...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //You can retrieve the actual UIImage
    _signupImgView.image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //Or you can get the image url from AssetsLibrary
    NSURL *path = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    imageSending=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:path]];
      imgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSending);//here i am converting as nsdata...
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

This is my post code

```
-(void)signupScreen:(NSString *)firstName :(NSString *)emailID :(NSString *)phoneNumber :(NSString *)password :(NSData *)img
{
    NSString *strSignupScreenRequest=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&email=%@&telephone=%@&password=%@&pic=%@""%@",firstName,emailID,phoneNumber,password,img];
    NSData *dataFetch=[strSignupScreenRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:localRegister]];
    [self requestFunction:url :dataFetch:NO];

}
```

This is my post method assigned globally....

```
else
    {
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *conLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)data.length];
        [request setValue:conLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        NSLog(@"post method ===%@",request);
    }
```

i have seen most of the people say AFNETWORKING is good way in that many file is there i don't know how to achieve please any one guide me....

Comment: Whats the actual issue? Did you try with `AFNetworking`?  If tried whats the error you're facing? Also, post the code of how you're uploading to it to your server.

Comment: Can you please put a breakpoint and check if your `imgdata ` has data and is not nil. Also, could you please share the code you are using to make server call and send this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     SomeImageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

Image is in `SomeImageView` now.You can convert it to `NSData`

```
 NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

and upload it using `multipart/form-data`
If you need code for that, Goto this tutorial. Best I could suggest : http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html

Comment: Sure, @KishoreKumar Let me know where you get the problem. Ready to help.

Comment: today I am not in office guide me tomorrow I will ping you at any point where I was struggle.

Comment: And Mark the answer as right, so that people having same problem as you , will directly land to the proper answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89991/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-mujib-saiyyed).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to transmit data to server. You are converting everything in `NSString` and then probably sending it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753099/how-send-nsdata-using-post-from-a-ios-application) is how you should do it. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434537/post-image-to-server-in-iphone) shows how to send image data along with other details. Read through all the answers.